# Overloading the equals operator in Fortran

Tags: oop, fortran, operator-overloading

Is there a way to overload the `=` operator so that you can write an assignment like in this example:

```
  module constants_mod
    integer,parameter :: dpn = selected_real_kind(14)
  end module

  module vectorField_mod
    use constants_mod
    implicit none
    private

    public :: vectorField
    public :: allocateX,allocateY,allocateZ
    public :: delete
    ! public :: operator(=)

    type vectorField
      integer,dimension(3) :: sx,sy,sz
      real(dpn),dimension(:,:,:),allocatable :: x,y,z
    end type

  interface delete
    module procedure deallocateVectorField
  end interface

  ! interface operator (=)
  !   module procedure vectorAssign
  ! end interface

  contains

    ! function vectorAssign(f) result(q)
    !   implicit none
    !   real(dpn),intent(in) :: f
    !   type(vectorField) :: q
    !   q%x = f; q%y = f; q%z = f
    ! end function

    ! subroutine vectorAssign(f,g)
    !   implicit none
    !   type(vectorField),intent(inout) :: f
    !   real(dpn),intent(in) :: g
    !   f%x = g; f%y = g; f%z = g
    ! end subroutine

    subroutine allocateX(field,Nx,Ny,Nz)
      implicit none
      type(vectorField),intent(inout) :: field
      integer,intent(in) :: Nx,Ny,Nz
      if (allocated(field%x)) deallocate(field%x)
      allocate(field%x(Nx,Ny,Nz))
      field%sx = shape(field%x)
    end subroutine

    subroutine allocateY(field,Nx,Ny,Nz)
      implicit none
      type(vectorField),intent(inout) :: field
      integer,intent(in) :: Nx,Ny,Nz
      if (allocated(field%y)) deallocate(field%y)
      allocate(field%y(Nx,Ny,Nz))
      field%sy = shape(field%y)
    end subroutine

    subroutine allocateZ(field,Nx,Ny,Nz)
      implicit none
      type(vectorField),intent(inout) :: field
      integer,intent(in) :: Nx,Ny,Nz
      if (allocated(field%z)) deallocate(field%z)
      allocate(field%z(Nx,Ny,Nz))
      field%sz = shape(field%z)
    end subroutine

    subroutine deallocateVectorField(field)
      implicit none
      type(vectorField),intent(inout) :: field
      deallocate(field%x,field%y,field%z)
      field%sx = 0; field%sy = 0; field%sz = 0
    end subroutine

  end module

  program test
  use constants_mod
  use vectorField_mod
  implicit none
  type(vectorField) :: a
  integer :: N = 1
  real(dpn) :: dt = 0.1
  call allocateX(a,N,N,N)
  call allocateY(a,N,N,N)
  call allocateZ(a,N,N,N)

  a%x = dble(1.0) ! want to avoid this
  a%y = dble(1.0) ! want to avoid this
  a%z = dble(1.0) ! want to avoid this

  a = real(1.0,dpn) ! want this instead (does not compile)

  call delete(a)

  end program
```

I've tried two different ways (shown in comments) but I get errors saying that there is a syntax error in generic specification (for publicizing the `=` operator).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For defined assignment `operator(=)` is not correct, but `assignment(=)` is: see Fortran 2008 12.4.3.4.3.  So you instead want the two lumps

```
public :: assignment (=)
```

and

```
interface assignment (=)
  module procedure vectorAssign
end interface
```

Note that the correct way to define the assignment is by the subroutine as you have it (although the assignee could have `intent(out)` instead of `intent(inout)`).

Comment: do you know if this is allowed in fortran 2003? My compiler doesn't recognize 2008 standards..

Comment: This dates back to Fortran 90.

Comment: If the lhs of the assignment is intent(out), what happens to the state of the object being assigned to? if the left-hand side owns a pointer, for instance, how can you make sure that it is safely deallocated before assigning to it?

Comment: @youngmit In many cases you can use a final subroutine for the derived type on the LHS.  On entry to the subroutine when associated with an `intent(out)` dummy the LHS will first be finalized.  Details can be found relating to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29038025/3157076) for example.

Answer (score 9):

`=` is not an operator, it is an assignment in Fortran and they are very different beasts.

To the classical possibility found in Fortran 90 and explained well in other answers, Fortran 2003 added a better possibility to bind the overloaded operators and assignments with the derived type.

This way you are sure you will not import the  type without the assignment (beware of public and private statement in this case!). It can have very unpleasant consequences and can be hard to debug:

```
type vectorField
  integer,dimension(3) :: sx,sy,sz
  real(dpn),dimension(:,:,:),allocatable :: x,y,z
contains
  procedure :: assignVector
  generic :: assignment(=) => assignVector
end type
```

This way you do not have to be that careful to not forget the `public :: assignment (=)`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can overload the assignment operator.  The syntax and requirements are different for the assignment operator than for other operators because the semantics are fundamentally different: all other operators compute a new value based on one or two arguments, without changing the arguments, whereas assignment changes the value of the left-hand argument.

In your case, I think it should look like this:

```
module vectorField_mod

! ...

  interface assignment (=)
    module procedure vectorAssign
  end interface

contains

  ! ...

  subroutine vectorAssign(f,g)
    implicit none
    type(vectorField),intent(out) :: f
    real(kind = dpn), intent(in) :: g
    f%x = g
    f%y = g
    f%z = g
  end subroutine vectorAssign

end module vectorField_mod
```