# Does deallocating a Fortran derived type automatically deallocate member arrays and pointers as well?

Tags: memory-leaks, fortran

In Fortran, if I have an allocatable array of derived types, each consisting of a pointer and an allocatable array,

```
type group
  real, pointer :: object
  real, allocatable :: objectData(:,:)
end type group

type(group), allocatable :: myGroup(:)
```

would I be able to deallocate all memory contained in this type by simply making a single call

```
deallocate(myGroup)
```

or do I need to deallocate the arrays within each type first, before deallocating the derived type:

```
do i = 1, size(myGroup)
  nullify(myGroup(i)%object)
  deallocate(myGroup(i)%objectData)
end do

deallocate(myGroup)
```

I'm leaning towards option 2 and nullifying all memory before deallocating the derived type, if not just to ensure that memory leaks aren't happening, but if option 1 is equivalent then that would be useful for future reference and save me a few lines of code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only allocatable components are automatically deallocated. You must deallocate pointers yourself.

Be careful, you have to **deallocate** the pointer, not just *nullify*. Nullifying it just removes the reference to the allocated memory. If you do not deallocate, a memory leak will happen.

Comment: Oops, good call on the reminder to deallocate pointers as well. Thanks! This answers my question.

Comment: You need to deallocate the pointer only if it was previously allocated and you do not use the allocated data anymore. But if the data is still being used, the nullify is OK. So the deallocation of the pointers is not a requirement, it depends on what you are doing.

Comment: @alexis Well of course, that is obvious. But that is not the topic of this question. The OP explicitly wants to *"be able to deallocate all memory contained in this type"*.

Comment: @Vladimir I understand, but if the pointer is not allocated I guess the memory is not "contained in this type" but elsewhere, right?. It is probably good to disappear any doubt...

Answer (score 4):

You know that the [allocatable components are deallocated automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29038146) but the pointers aren't.  But for

> would I be able to deallocate all memory contained in this type by simply making a single call

the answer is: yes (with some effort).

If the type `group` is *finalizable* then an entity of that type is finalized when it is deallocated.

```
type group
  real, pointer :: object
  real, allocatable :: objectData(:,:)
 contains
  final tidy_up
end type group
```

for the procedure

```
subroutine tidy_up(myGroup_array)
  type(group), intent(inout) :: myGroup_array(:)
  ! ... deallocate the pointers in the elements of the array
end subroutine
```

You can use this finalization to take care of the pointer components.

Finally, be aware of [some subtleties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28548581).  Also note that this somewhat reduces your control over whether the pointer is deallocated (there are many times you wouldn't want it to be).

Comment: I always forget about this, because gfortran is still somewhat behind, but after full support it will be a great thing.

Comment: That's another caveat: one needs compiler support.