# How to properly finalize an object in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, finalizer

I have an object parsing a textfile. Here's my main program:

```
program main
use Parser_class 
implicit none
type(Parser) :: Parser
call Parser%ProcessFile('data.txt')
call Parser%Deallocate
end program main
```

where the type definition is

```
module Parser_class
type :: Parser
contains
    procedure, public :: ProcessFile
    procedure, public :: Deallocate
end type Parser
contains
    subroutine ProcessFile(self)
    ...
    end subroutine 
    subroutine Deallocate(self)
    class(Parser) :: self
    ...
    end subroutine 
end module Parser_class
```

I read about the final keyword and altered the type definition to

```
module Parser_class
type :: Parser
contains
    procedure, public :: ProcessFile
    final :: Deallocate
end type Parser
contains
    subroutine ProcessFile(self)
    ...
    end subroutine 
    subroutine Deallocate(self)
    type(Parser) :: self
    ...
    end subroutine 
end module Parser_class
```

Additionally, in the main program I don't have `call Parser%Deallocate` anymore. The finalizer doesn't get called now at any time. I somehow get this is because I never destroy or overwrite the `Parser` object. But how could I do this, or what is the proper way to handle the deallocation process?

Comment: I added the `end program`. The program works as intended (just reads the textfiles). I just want to know if my way of using `call Parser%Deallocate` is the right way to deallocate all arrays or if i should do it with finalizers. Additional question is when exactly finalizers get called. Can't provide a working example though, i'm fairly new to O-O Fortran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Fortran 2008 standard, when finalization comes about is given in section 4.5.6.3<sup>1</sup>.  I won't copy all the times here, but I will summarize.

What is clearly mentioned following from when, is when not:

> If image execution is terminated, either by an error (e.g. an allocation failure) or by execution of a stop-stmt, error-stop-stmt, or end-program-stmt, entities existing immediately prior to termination are not finalized.

This covers your program.  `Parser` is in the program's scope and it still exists at the end of the program.  There are no apparent other things which would cause finalization.

If `Deallocate` is a final procedure for the type, then there are subtle ways in which finalization of an object of that type differ from a call of the type-bound procedure.  In finalization, the process is recursive: components and parents are themselves subject to finalization.  With a subroutine call that recursion must appear manually in some way.

In many cases one doesn't care that an entity isn't finalized at the end of the program.  After all, any deallocation is then the operating system's problem, not the programmer's.  However, there are times other forms of tidying up are indeed desirable.

True finalization can be forced in some ways.  If the list below is examined, two options come to mind:

- make the `Parser` object allocatable and explicitly deallocate it;
- wrap the whole thing in a `block` construct.

---

To crudely summarize when finalization happens:

- when there's deallocation (pointer or allocatable);
- as procedure start-up with `intent(out)` arguments;
- when reaching the end of an executable construct or subprogram, for non-saved local objects;
- just before intrinsic assignment to a variable;
- after the value of a function's result is finished with.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you aren't reading the final form of the document you'll want to pretend [paragraphs 5 and 7 don't exist](http://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-158r1.txt).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I learned that i should always deallocate everything i allocate to not create memory leaks. Is that obsolete? So it would be fine to not call the deallocate subroutines and just let the program end?

Comment: If it's just memory deallocation, then memory leaks aren't a concern at the end of the program.  They may be when pointers are used in certain ways, where finalization [would indeed help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29038025), but again even with these not at the end of the program.  Allocatables generally are "safe".

Comment: @THo It is obsolete in languages which use garbage collection or reference counting. Fortran's allocatable variables are a very simple form of reference counting where count can be only one. You don't have to deallocate allocatable variables explicitly if you don't need to free the memory or allocate it again to something else.