# "C pointer trickery" to allow mismatched Fortran array ranks

Tags: pointers, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'm writing a HDF5 wrapper subroutine that will read/write a double precision array of *any* shape from/to a dataset inside a HDF5 file. To achieve this, I use some C pointer trickery such that the subroutine takes in only the first element of the array as `val`, but it actually reads/writes the whole array using the temporary buffer `buf(1:sz_buf)`.

So far I have the following for the read subroutine (after removing error checks to keep it concise):

```
SUBROUTINE hdf5_read_array_d( fname, path, name, val, dims )
  USE ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_SIZE_T, C_LOC, C_F_POINTER

  ! Input arguments
  CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN) :: fname, path, name
  REAL(KIND(1.D0)), TARGET, INTENT(OUT) :: val
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: dims

  ! Internal variables
  INTEGER(KIND=HID_T) :: h5root, h5path, h5dset
  INTEGER(KIND=HSIZE_T), DIMENSION(SIZE(dims)) :: h5dims
  REAL(KIND(1.D0)), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: buf
  INTEGER(KIND=C_SIZE_T) :: sz_buf
  INTEGER :: dim

  ! Open the file in read-only mode
  CALL h5fopen_f( TRIM(fname), H5F_ACC_RDONLY_F, h5root, ierr )

  ! Open the pre-existing path in the file as a group
  CALL h5gopen_f( h5root, TRIM(path), h5path, ierr )

  ! Open the dataset
  CALL h5dopen_f( h5path, TRIM(name), h5dset, ierr )

  ! Convert dims to HSIZE_T
  h5dims(:) = dims(:)

  ! C pointer trickery: cast double -> void* -> double*
  sz_buf = PRODUCT(dims)
  ALLOCATE( buf( sz_buf ) )
  CALL C_F_POINTER( C_LOC(val), buf, (/sz_buf/) )

  ! Read data from dataset through buffer
  CALL h5dread_f( h5dset, H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, buf, h5dims, ierr )

  ! Clean up and close HDF5 file
  NULLIFY(buf)
  CALL h5dclose_f( h5dset, ierr )
  CALL h5gclose_f( h5path, ierr )
  CALL h5fclose_f( h5root, ierr )

  RETURN
END SUBROUTINE hdf5_read_array_d
```

Now, the question is, do I need to also put in `DEALLOCATE(buf)` in addition to / in place of the `NULLIFY(buf)`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I am aware that Fortran 2018 includes assumed-rank arrays `val(..)` that will elegantly solve this problem. But again, it's a newer feature that might not be implemented by all compilers yet.

Edit: On `C_F_POINTER()`, here's a screenshot of Metcalf, Reid, and Cohen (4th Edition, not the newest one that has Fortran 2018 stuff):
[image: Metcalf_et_al_C_F_POINTER]

Comment: Ouch.  It's been a while since I've seen code where UPPER CASE was a STANDARD CODING STYLE CONVENTION ;)  It's also been a while since I looked at Fortran (F77 had a good, 20-year run as "standard" ;)), so "NULLIFY()" and "DEALLOCATE()" strike me as "newer features".  But we digress ;) Yes, I believe you need both DEALLOCATE() and NULLIFY() here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29038146/421195

Comment: Yes, that answers my question. I guess the part that confuses me is whether calling `DEALLOCATE(buf)` will also deallocate the target `val` array. On the upper case usage, I guess it's a matter of style; I consistently use them in Modern Fortran (not FORTRAN) for reserved keywords and intrinsic procedure names (:

Comment: What do you think the routine C_F_POINTER does?  Note the second argument, buf in your code, is Intent( Out )

Comment: Why do you want to allocate `buf` then immediately throw away the pointer to that allocated memory by pointing `buf` at something else? The general principle of the linked question (any pointer you allocate, deallocate) holds, but here you don't want to allocate it and you don't need to nullify it.

Comment: @IanBush `val` is INTENT(OUT) to which data from the HDF5 file will be written into, while `buf` is just a temporary buffer. C_F_POINTER() executes the pointer trickery by first taking the address of `val` as a C `void*` pointer, then converting it back into `REAL(dp)` Fortran pointer `buf`.

Comment: @francescalus While I can see why you have closed this as a duplicate to the linked question I think this is slightly different - hence my vote to reopen. I think in this case the OP has essentially confused the Intents of C_F_Pointer - thinking that it makes the first argument being an alias to the second, akin how C pointers work. But I admit I am trying to mind read here

Comment: @wyphan No. Almost precisely the wrong way around. C_Loc(val) is Intent( In ), buf is Intent( Out ). Thus any memory you have associated with buf prior to the call will be lost.

Comment: @francescalus I allocated `buf` to have enough space to read the data through `buf` using HDF5, then point it at `val` (which is an array of the same size or bigger than `buf` with any rank) so that the HDF5 call actually writes directly to `val` ("zero-copy" scheme)

Comment: @IanBush `val` is INTENT(OUT) and TARGET. `buf` is a temporary rank-1 pointer array local to the subroutine. Yes, I intended to "emulate" how C pointers work in Fortran without writing actual glue code in C.

Comment: The allocation of `buf` has no impact at all on memory used for processing `val`.  After the `c_f_pointer` call the memory used is that `val` initially had and the memory allocated through `buf` is entirely inaccessible.

Comment: @wyphan Please see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/C_005fF_005fPOINTER.html or a good book like Metcalf, Reid and Cohen. The first argument is Intent( In ). The second argument is Intent( Out ). You can't change that. That is how C_F_Pointer works

Comment: @francescalus So... does that mean I have created a memory leak the exact moment I call `C_F_POINTER()` on an allocated pointer array?

Comment: @IanBush What a coincidence, I have Metcalf, Reid, and Cohen open in my PDF viewer. I'll update the question with a screenshot of the description for `C_F_POINTER`.

Comment: "does that mean I have created a memory leak the exact moment I call `C_F_POINTER()` on an allocated pointer array?" Yes, exactly that.

Comment: @francescalus Then, what's the proper way to enforce the proper size of `buf` to be the product of `dims`? Perhaps you can write an elegant answer to the question?

Comment: @francescalus I intend to use the subroutine like this: `ALLOCATE(mat(1000,1000,5)); CALL hdf5_read_array_d( 'file.hdf5', '/', 'mat', mat(1,1,2), (/1000,1000,1/) )` to fill in `mat(:,:,2)`, for instance. Note that `val` is a scalar argument, even though I meant to fill an array section; this design is influenced by MPI.

Comment: `buf` takes shape `[sz_buf]` after that `c_f_pointer` call: that's what the shape argument is for. You simply don't need to allocate `buf` first: it uses the memory (sequence) that `val` already had

Comment: I've had a couple of beers, so I don't trust myself to answer properly now, but the way I would solve this if I couldn't be bothered to write the complete set of overloaded routines, which is the proper way, is via an assumed size array, not via C-interoperability at all. If nobody has answered this by the time I sober up then I'll write an answer. It's not perfect, but Fortran is not good at addressing what you are trying to do - TKR matching of arguments is a good thing, embrace it!

Comment: @IanBush I agree, TKR matching is a step in the right direction. I think it's too much work to write 7 (or is it 15 now?) different subroutines for overloading, where the takes in A(:), the second A(:,:), and so on... It's just that compiler writers sometimes don't come up with the implementation fast enough to gain mainstream acceptance... so I'm just trying to write code that is as portable as possible, for now.

Comment: Note assumed *size* NOT assumed *rank* . Implementations of assumed size predate me using Fortran, and you don't want to know how long that is!

Answer (score 4):

You can use C-style pointer trickery to do what you want, but you have some things to address in your approach:

- you have a memory leak with `allocate(buf)`
- you are (subtly) lying about the scalar nature of `val`
- you'll horribly confuse anyone reading your code

The reason why this is horribly confusing, is because you don't need to do this trickery. That's also why I won't show you how to do it, or to address the question "do I need to deallocate as well as nullify?".

You know that you have an array `val` to stuff `n` values in, in a contiguous lump. You worry that that can't do that because you (without using an assumed-rank dummy) have to match array shape.  Worry not.

```
  integer :: a(2,2,2,2), b(4,2,2), c(4,4)
```

are all arrays with 16 elements.  So is

```
  integer :: d(16)
```

You can associate actual arguments `a`, `b` and `c` with dummy argument `d`.  Let's see that in action:

```
  implicit none

  integer :: a(2,2,2,2), b(4,2,2), c(4,4)

  call set_them(a, SHAPE(a))
  call set_them(b, SHAPE(b))
  call set_them(c, SHAPE(c))

  print '(16I3)', a, b, c

contains

  subroutine set_them(d, dims)
    integer, intent(in)  :: dims(:)
    integer, intent(out) :: d(PRODUCT(dims))

    integer i
    d=[(i,i=1,SIZE(d))]
  end subroutine

end program
```

You can even associate array sections in this way to define portions.

You can see several other questions around here about this *sequence association*, in particular looking at changing shapes of arrays. This answer is more of a motivation of what to look for when tempted to do something complicated instead.

Comment: Interesting, didn't realize this is even possible using automatic arrays! But will the compiler be smart enough to perform zero-copy for array slices?

Comment: On the other hand, I think the C pointer trickery is still needed if I want to write similar HDF5 subroutines that deal with the complex data type, since HDF5 doesn't natively support them. I'm thinking `double _Complex -> void* -> double*` casting using `C_F_POINTER()`, or something like `std::reinterpret_cast()` in C++. Unless I want to be sloppy and mix together `REAL` and `COMPLEX` types... which I know GFortran 10 isn't happy about.

Comment: `d` isn't an automatic array (because it's a dummy). As long as the (compiler knows that the) actual argument array (whole or section) is contiguous it should avoid doing any copy-in/copy-out for the argument passing. Simply contiguous ones (like the whole array `a` and the section `a(:,:,:,1)`) are designed so that compilers can do this.

Comment: Also, since when is the `[` and `]` characters part of the Fortran standard? That's a lot nicer looking than `(/` and `/)`.

Comment: Since almost 20 years ago.